# how to keep the css style after inserting a row to table by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a css style

```
    #mytbody > tr > th {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

And the script

```
    function myclick() {
        $("#mytbody").append("<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td>/tr>");
    }
```

Here's my html code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>head 1</td>
            <td>head 2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="mytbody">
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="myclick()">button</button>
```

The css style disappeared for the new line that added by clicking the button.

[image: result]

Why the css doesn't work for the adding line and how to keep the css style for adding new line?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Give a class to every row and on `myclick()` take that class as well

Comment: No  `th` element is appended at `.append("<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td>/tr>");`. Do you want to apply `css` to `tr` or `td` element?

Comment: The <th> tag defines a header cell in an HTML table. Therefore use <th> in the thead section and use <td> in tbody. Td tag defines table data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because your css is only for the `th` tag. You should add css for `td` as well:

```
#mytbody > tr > th,
#mytbody > tr > td {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer,

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#mytbody").append("<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>");
});
```

```css
 

#mytbody > tr > th {
    background-color: red;
}
#mytbody > tr > td {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
   

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>head 1</td>
            <td>head 2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="mytbody">
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
        </tr>     
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button">button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will not repeat answers from previous examples but want to mention something realated to this.

If you load complete table via ajax and forgot to put `<thead>` or `<tbody>` inside your code, you can expirience the similar problem with CSS especially if you use Bootstrap.

Many developers not use that tags inside tables and browsers fix that in DOM but when you load with ajax you will not get that tags if you not define before in file and that can break CSS also.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the main reason, from the information you provided, is that the CSS declaration doesn't actually correspond to the added elements. Your style declaration is only for the `th` tags but not the `td` tags.

Try something like this:

```
#mytbody > tr > th,
#mytbody > tr > td {
  background-color: red;
}
```